# Spring application failed to start, multiple ConversionService, webFluxConversionService and intergationConversionService

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-webflux

Using **spring-boot-starter-webflux** and **spring-boot-starter-integration** within a Spring Boot 2.0.8.RELEASE application, two `ConversionService`s will get registered, `webFluxConversionService` and `integrationConversionService`
The Spring Application fails to start and expects one of those beans.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeServiceAdapterImpl {

 @Qualifier("webFluxConversionService")
 private final ConversionService conversionService;

 // SOME METHOD
}


Error messages

APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in 
de.test.service.SomeServiceAdapterImpl required a single bean,
 but 2 were found:
    - webFluxConversionService: defined by method 'webFluxConversionService' in org.springframework.web.reactive.config.DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration
    - integrationConversionService: defined in null


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to show the `@Bean` for `de.test.service.SomeServiceAdapterImpl`. But, essentially, if you need a conversion service, you need to specify which one (presumably the webflux one); just follow the instructions in the error message.

Add `@Qualifier("webFluxConversionService")` to the `ConversionService` parameter in the bean factory method.

Comment: @Qualifier annotation didn't help. The concrete class FormattingConversionService fixed the problem. Actually not a cool fix. I would like to use the interface instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the primary bean:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ConversionService defaultConversionService(@Qualifier("webFluxConversionService") ConversionService conversionService) {
    return conversionService;
}
```